# How can I wget a series of directories, taking only the highest of a set of numbered directories (and its subdirs/files)?

Tags: wget

I'm looping over a series of top-level directories that all have a similar structure beneath, like so:

`some_dir/some_other_dir/a_different_dir/{1,2,3,4,5,6...}`

I would like to pull only the highest numbered subdirectory (and its contents) beneath `a_different_dir` using wget. The numbering scheme is different for each top level directory, and progresses on a regular basis. The highest numbered directory is also always the newest, chronologically.

Right now I have:

`wget -nH --timestamping --recursive --no-parent --cut-dirs=3 http://website.com/some_dir/some_other_dir/a_different_dir/`

This downloads everything, of course, but I have neither the disk space to store nor the time to download all the contents to make `--timestamping` effective for this situation.

I only have access over http. What's the best way to automate this?

Comment: HTTP in itself doesn't have any functionality for directory listings. Is that web server delivering you a HTML page with a directory listing, or how do you know which files exist?

Comment: Yep, it's delivering me a plain HTML page with directory browsing.

Comment: so, get that page, use any HTML-parsing tool you like, and get the last entry only? I don't think `wget` is the tool of choice here.